# Unit root Test on binary Variables

Tags: r, statistics, time-series

I am working on idea of how Unit roots test will perform on binary variables. But I got some unexpected results:

```
library(quantmod)
library(tseries)
library (urca)
library (forecast)

getSymbols("MSFT")


 names(MSFT)<-c("Open", "High", "Low", "Close", "Volume", "Adjusted.Close")
 p<-data.frame(MSFT)

 n=length(p$Adjusted.Close)
# d; third column indicates direction of market.
 d<-cbind(tdy=p$Adjusted.Close[1:n-1],twm=p$Adjusted.Close[2:n],
      direct=sign( p$Adjusted.Close[2:n]-p$Adjusted.Close[1:n-1]))

plot(d[1:100,3],type="l",col = "blue")


table (d[,3])

d<-ts(d)
Ar.model <- auto.arima(d[,3], stationary = TRUE, seasonal = FALSE, ic="aic")

print(Ar.model)

    Series: d[, 3] 
    ARIMA(2,0,2) with zero mean     

    Coefficients:
     ar1      ar2      ma1     ma2
    0.0213  -0.8571  -0.0489  0.8692
     s.e.     NaN      NaN      NaN     NaN

 sigma^2 estimated as 0.9859:  log likelihood=-3843.91
   AIC=7697.82   AICc=7697.84   BIC=7727.37
   Warning message:
   In sqrt(diag(x$var.coef)) : NaNs produced
```

As you can see, the S.E. are NaN. I was wondering may be I am facing a unit root process. So I run ADF test:

```
  ho_adf <- ur.df(d[,3])
  summary(ho_adf)

############################################### 
# Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test Unit Root Test # 
############################################### 

Test regression none 


Call:
lm(formula = z.diff ~ z.lag.1 - 1 + z.diff.lag)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.0376 -0.9786  0.9624  1.0081  1.0376 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
z.lag.1    -1.021448   0.027505 -37.136   <2e-16 ***
z.diff.lag -0.008069   0.019173  -0.421    0.674    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.9938 on 2720 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.5149,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.5146 
F-statistic:  1444 on 2 and 2720 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16


Value of test-statistic is: -37.1364 

Critical values for test statistics: 
      1pct  5pct 10pct
tau1 -2.58 -1.95 -1.62
```

We know that H0 of ADF-test declares unit root in data. The p-value and test-statistics above rejects H0. Meaning that we can reject unit root existence. Now, my questions:

1. Why I get NaN is S.E in absence of unit root of data?
2. How can I fix the problem of S.E.? ( i don't want to use other ADF.test functions of R, I am aware of KPSS and PP tests already;
   unless it is related to just Binary Times series data. Meaning that
   your recommending specific Unit root test for binary time series.
   like BARMA. In this case, the question arises why ADF test fails?)

Answer (score 0):

I ran your codes and the results are:

```
> print(Ar.model)
Series: d[, 3] 
ARIMA(2,0,2) with non-zero mean 

Coefficients:
          ar1      ar2     ma1     ma2    mean
      -0.0566  -0.8144  0.0208  0.8187  0.0262
s.e.   0.1570   0.1050  0.1506  0.1122  0.0183

sigma^2 estimated as 0.9852:  log likelihood=-3997.69
AIC=8007.39   AICc=8007.42   BIC=8043.08
```

perhaps you can retry it.